# Convert Table to another format in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am facing a problem with MS-SQL in getting output from a table in a particular format.

```
Name        |    StringValue            |    Parent_ID
FieldName   |    TestHeader1            |    3
FieldValue  |    ValueForTestHeader1    |    3
FieldName   |    TestHeader2            |    6
FieldValue  |    ValueForTestHeader2    |    6
```

And I want to select data from this table as follows:

```
TestHeader1             |     TestHeader2
ValueForTestHeader1     |     ValueForTestHeader2
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation by using `row_number()` & `dense_rank()`:

```
select  max(case when seq1 = 1 then stringvalue end),
        max(case when seq1 = 2 then stringvalue end)
from (select t.*, 
             dense_rank() over (order by parent_id) as seq1,
             row_number() over (partition by parent_id order by stringvalue) seq2
      from table t
     ) t
group by seq2;
```

Answer (score 0):

use conditional aggregation

```
select max(case when parent_id=3 then stringvalue)  as col1,
max(case when parent_id=6 then stringvalue)  as col2
from tablename
group by parent_id
```